# unrecognized import path "syscall/js"

Tags: go, import, importerror

I am trying to use webassembly but I can't run this

```
import (
    "syscall/js"
)
```

or

```
GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js go get -u github.com/siongui/godom/wasm
```

to install wasm

It throws me an error

```
cannot find package "syscall/js" in any of:
```

I am using go version go1.6.2 linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Go 1.11 Release Notes (August 2018)](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11)
>
> [WebAssembly](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#wasm)
>
> Go programs can call into JavaScript using the new experimental
>   `syscall/js` package.

---

`syscall/js` was first introduced in Go1.11 (August 2018). Your output from the command `go version` is `go1.6.2 l`, an ancient (February 2016) and obsolete version.

---

After downloading a binary release of Go1.11 or later suitable for your system from [Go Downloads](https://golang.org/dl/), please follow the [installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install), including the instructions for [Uninstalling Go](https://golang.org/doc/install#uninstall) for your current version of Go.

Answer (score 2):

There are some breaking changes in **Go1.12** in **syscall/js**

> The `Callback` type and `NewCallback` function have been renamed; they are now called `Func` and `FuncOf`, respectively. This is a breaking change, but WebAssembly support is still experimental and not yet subject to the Go 1 compatibility promise. Any code using the old names will need to be updated.
>
> If a type implements the new Wrapper interface, `ValueOf` will use it to return the JavaScript value for that type.
>
> The meaning of the zero `Value` has changed. It now represents the JavaScript undefined value instead of the number zero. This is a breaking change, but WebAssembly support is still experimental and not yet subject to the Go 1 compatibility promise. Any code relying on the zero Value to mean the number zero will need to be updated.
>
> The new `Value.Truthy` method reports the JavaScript "truthiness" of a given value.

---

Here is a link to an example that uses React, Node and Go to get a clearer understanding.

https://github.com/phmatray/webassembly-demo